# How do I Equip Pack DLC After I Buy it?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I have bought the Call of Duty Black Ops 2's Personalization Pack DLC, but I cannot view this pack on my gun, only on my calling card. How do I  equip it on my gun?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are for the Xbox360 version, but the menu names are the same if you own a different version:

1. Go to your gun in the `Create A Class` menu.
2. Select your weapon of choice, and press `Y` to bring up the skin selection menu.
3. Use RB and LB to cycle through the different pages of add-ons:

   - pressing RB once will bring you to the screen where you can add a Clan Tag or your emblem to your gun
   - pressing RB again will put you on the DLC skins page
4. Select your DLC pack and enjoy!